# Google Maps SDK conflict between different frameworks in one app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-maps-ios-utils

We are working on an iOS project which is using two different frameworks (AAA Library map)& (our own Reward Framework) and both use Google Maps framework. The issue we are facing is the conflict between these frameworks. What happens is when we load the Map from either one of the frameworks, the first one loads up fine but on the second one the App crashes. We have tried with every possible way to debug it but unfortunately we couldn't. We have exhausted many a days to explore this problem, on stackoverflow as well as any other helpful blog but unfortunately we're still stuck. Any help on this regard will be more than helpful.

We have verified both Frameworks by using the same Version of Google Map SDK> 2.2.0

**AAA MAP Library Crash** Log Attached below
 **Crashed with signal SIGSEGV (code SEGV_ACCERR, address=0x20)**

```
Incident Identifier: 2A1C005F-2363-4C50-B161-CD5E117BAEE7
CrashReporter Key:   6bb28012df77c6e754e6d45acf729c3018a02007
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             CAA [261]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/726AAC93-D46D-436C-A928-C0B1FE360B4A/CAA.app/CAA

Version:             6.23.0913 (6.23.0913)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]



Date/Time:           2017-09-18 16:34:01.4302 +0500
Launch Time:         2017-09-18 16:33:31.8189 +0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018520fd44 0x1851fc000 + 81220
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018520fd44 0x1851fc000 + 81220
2   Foundation                      0x00000001871c7f3c 0x18718d000 + 241468
3   Foundation                      0x00000001871c7ea0 0x18718d000 + 241312
4   Foundation                      0x00000001871c62ac 0x18718d000 + 234156
5   Foundation                      0x00000001871c31cc 0x18718d000 + 221644
6   Foundation                      0x00000001871c2a60 0x18718d000 + 219744
7   Foundation                      0x00000001871c2750 0x18718d000 + 218960
8   CAA                             0x00000001007c6240 -[GMSDisplayLink addClient:forRunLoopModes:] + 1056
9   CAA                             0x00000001007c5de8 -[GMSDisplayLink addClient:] + 144
10  CAA                             0x000000010077392c -[GMSEntityRendererView setUpRenderer] + 156
11  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cf880 0x18c8c5000 + 43136
12  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfd6c 0x18c8c5000 + 44396
13  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfc50 0x18c8c5000 + 44112
14  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfd88 0x18c8c5000 + 44424
15  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfc50 0x18c8c5000 + 44112
16  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfd88 0x18c8c5000 + 44424
17  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfc50 0x18c8c5000 + 44112
18  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfd88 0x18c8c5000 + 44424
19  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfc50 0x18c8c5000 + 44112
20  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfd88 0x18c8c5000 + 44424
21  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfc50 0x18c8c5000 + 44112
22  UIKit                           0x000000018c8dbda8 0x18c8c5000 + 93608
23  UIKit                           0x000000018c8dbbc8 0x18c8c5000 + 93128
24  UIKit                           0x000000018c9962f4 0x18c8c5000 + 856820
25  UIKit                           0x000000018c98c764 0x18c8c5000 + 816996
26  UIKit                           0x000000018c98b870 0x18c8c5000 + 813168
27  UIKit                           0x000000018c98b424 0x18c8c5000 + 812068
28  UIKit                           0x000000018c98b388 0x18c8c5000 + 811912
29  UIKit                           0x000000018c8d1cc0 0x18c8c5000 + 52416
30  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189ac2274 0x1899ab000 + 1143412
31  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189ab6de8 0x1899ab000 + 1097192
32  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189ab6ca8 0x1899ab000 + 1096872
33  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189a3234c 0x1899ab000 + 553804
34  QuartzCore                      0x0000000189a593ac 0x1899ab000 + 713644
35  UIKit                           0x000000018cb53168 0x18c8c5000 + 2679144
36  UIKit                           0x000000018d0c9404 0x18c8c5000 + 8406020
37  UIKit                           0x000000018d0c95a8 0x18c8c5000 + 8406440
38  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018675142c 0x186676000 + 898092
39  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186750d9c 0x186676000 + 896412
40  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018674e9a8 0x186676000 + 887208
41  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018667eda4 0x186676000 + 36260
42  GraphicsServices                0x00000001880e9074 0x1880dd000 + 49268
43  UIKit                           0x000000018c939c9c 0x18c8c5000 + 478364
44  CAA                             0x000000010011682c main (main.m:14)
45  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018568d59c 0x185689000 + 17820
```

**REWARD Framework Crash** Log is

```
Incident Identifier: 9F61D68F-E3A5-474D-8CE0-6252C0973422
CrashReporter Key:   6bb28012df77c6e754e6d45acf729c3018a02007
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Process:             CAA [264]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/726AAC93-D46D-436C-A928-C0B1FE360B4A/CAA.app/CAA

Version:             6.23.0913 (6.23.0913)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]



Date/Time:           2017-09-18 16:34:28.1863 +0500
Launch Time:         2017-09-18 16:34:07.2193 +0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.3 (14G60)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018520fd44 0x1851fc000 + 81220
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018520fd44 0x1851fc000 + 81220
2   Foundation                      0x00000001871c7f3c 0x18718d000 + 241468
3   Foundation                      0x00000001871c7ea0 0x18718d000 + 241312
4   Foundation                      0x00000001871c62ac 0x18718d000 + 234156
5   Foundation                      0x00000001871c31cc 0x18718d000 + 221644
6   Foundation                      0x00000001871c2a60 0x18718d000 + 219744
7   Foundation                      0x00000001871c2750 0x18718d000 + 218960
8   CAA_Reward                      0x0000000101d03c40 0x101aa0000 + 2505792
9   CAA_Reward                      0x0000000101d037e8 0x101aa0000 + 2504680
10  CAA_Reward                      0x0000000101ca8b08 0x101aa0000 + 2132744
11  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cf880 0x18c8c5000 + 43136
12  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfd6c 0x18c8c5000 + 44396
13  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfc50 0x18c8c5000 + 44112
14  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfd88 0x18c8c5000 + 44424
15  UIKit                           0x000000018c8cfc50 0x18c8c5000 + 44112
16  UIKit                           0x000000018c8dbda8 0x18c8c5000 + 93608
17  UIKit                           0x000000018c8dbbc8 0x18c8c5000 + 93128
18  CAA_Reward                      0x0000000101adb0b8 0x101aa0000 + 241848
19  UIKit                           0x000000018c909c54 0x18c8c5000 + 281684
20  UIKit                           0x000000018c909bd4 0x18c8c5000 + 281556
21  UIKit                           0x000000018c8f4148 0x18c8c5000 + 192840
22  UIKit                           0x000000018c9094b8 0x18c8c5000 + 279736
23  UIKit                           0x000000018c908fd4 0x18c8c5000 + 278484
24  UIKit                           0x000000018c90436c 0x18c8c5000 + 258924
25  UIKit                           0x000000018c8d4f80 0x18c8c5000 + 65408
26  UIKit                           0x000000018d0cea20 0x18c8c5000 + 8428064
27  UIKit                           0x000000018d0c917c 0x18c8c5000 + 8405372
28  UIKit                           0x000000018d0c95a8 0x18c8c5000 + 8406440
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018675142c 0x186676000 + 898092
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186750d9c 0x186676000 + 896412
31  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018674e9a8 0x186676000 + 887208
32  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018667eda4 0x186676000 + 36260
33  GraphicsServices                0x00000001880e9074 0x1880dd000 + 49268
34  UIKit                           0x000000018c939c9c 0x18c8c5000 + 478364
35  CAA                             0x00000001000ba82c main (main.m:14)
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018568d59c 0x185689000 + 17820
```

Comment: Please show your code and mention the names of these frameworks, otherwise it is close to impossible to give you an exact answer.

Comment: As you said already google maps included in your project by using another Framework. Then try to avoid separate google maps framework adding into your project. Try to import the google maps where ever you want it. Also share the code if possible

Comment: I have update My question. Please review this.

Comment: Any one have the answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Once i have the same problem. I was trying to add Bolts and FacebookSDK at same time. And i was getting duplicate error. I searched and somewhere i find the solution.
I added both sdk using Pods

```
pod 'Bolts-SDK'
pod 'Facebook-SDK', 'sdk_version'
```

Try to add frameworks using PODS.

Comment: Sorry your solution do not solve this problem. We have try to add Google map SDK with pod but not working.

Comment: Basically its not the pod dependency that is used per say in these frameworks. These are open ended frameworks like CoreLocation in iOS and need to be added manually. These frameworks use GoogleMaps SDK  internally. Hence your answer is invalid. Thank you though, for answering.